# Do Kubernetes cron jobs have readiness and/or liveness probes?

Tags: kubernetes

If I am starting a container in Kubernetes and I want to run it as a cronjob, is there a way that I can tell that the containers is ready to be ran?  I have a collection of short-lived containers instead of background services. I'd like something that'd test it, prior to run, similar to how readiness probes work for services.

Answer (score 0):

The "readiness probe" is for determining whether the pod can receive traffic from the cluster.  Cronjobs aren't intended to receive traffic from the cluster, so a readiness probe is pointless.

I'm having trouble correlating your subject line with the content of your question.

It is pointless to check if a container is "ready to run" for a cronjob. The container is not created until the cronjob instance is run according to the schedule.

Comment: That's kinda what I figured, the problem is the cronjob may have problems that prevent it from being ready to run.  It's not necessarily pointless, to me at least, just definitely not how Kubernetes was designed.